# About the double to be a garbled

Tags: java, android, sqlite, double, android-cursor

I want get the sqlite data to ArrayList but I dont know why the data would become a garbled.
Can someone tell me the solution?

```
List<double[]> y = new ArrayList<double[]>(); 
Cursor vocabCursor = database.query(HIST_TABLE,
                        new String[]{QUIZ_WHAT, QUIZ_SCORE},
                    QUIZ_WHAT + "='Vocabulary Quiz'",
                                null, null, null, null);
vocabCursor.moveToFirst();
if(!vocabCursor.isAfterLast()) {
    do {
        double name = vocabCursor.getDouble(1);
    y.add(new double[]{name});
} while (vocabCursor.moveToNext());
}
vocabCursor.close();

Log.d("y",y);
```

The result of the log:

> [D@45fe5220, [D@45fe288, [D@45fe52a8, [D@45fe52c8]

Comment: You have a `List<double[]>`, i.e. a `List` of `double` arrays, whereas I think what you want is actually a `List<Double>`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the output of `toString()` applied to double array objects.

Your list contains at most one value per entry so consider using a `List<Double>` (note the capital D)  instead.